# Is there a better way than using python-docx to extract text-chunks from a high amount of unstructured MS Word-documents?

Tags: python, information-retrieval, text-extraction, python-docx

For a text-classification problem I need to extract a huge amount of text-chunks out of Word documents. I need to write these chunks of text into a jsonlines-file so the text can be annotated using an annotation tool. The function that I wrote is thisone:

```
def writeParagraphsToFile(filename):
    textblocks = []
    paragraphs = []
    txtblock = ""
    para_ID = 0
    lineNr = 0
    startNum = re.compile(r'\A\d+')
    startsWithWhitespaces = re.compile(r'\A\s+')
    d = Document(path2 + filename)
    amountOfPara = len(d.paragraphs)


    for p in d.paragraphs:
        lineNr += 1        

        if (lineNr == 1):   
            titel = p.text



        elif(lijnNr > 1 and startNum.match(p.text)):
            TuTitel = ""
            if txtblock != "":
                textblocks.append(txtblok)
            txtblok = ""

            for run in p.runs:
                if run.bold and run.underline:
                    TuTitel += " "+run.text

        elif (lineNr >1):
            if p.text == "":
                txtblock += "\n"     
            elif len(p.text)>6:
                txtblok += " "+p.text
                if lineNr == amountOfPara-1:
                    textblocks.append(txtblok)


    for tb in textblocks:
        paragraphs.append(tb.strip().splitlines())


    paragrafen_nieuw = [p for p in paragrafen if p]


    for r in paragrafen_nieuw:
        for t in r:
            if t != "":
                para_ID +=1
                writer.write({"text": t.lstrip(), "meta": {"Bestandsnaam": filename, "Doc_id": getDocID(filename), "Para_id": para_ID}})
```

This code works for 1 specific kind of Word Documents, namely those ones that start with 1 line which is the document title and where the subtitles start with a number and are written in "bold" & "underline" font.

The problem is: I have MANY documents, with MANY layouts. Some start with a title, some don't, some start with a title existing out of 2 lines, some have actual "heading 1", "heading 2"-attributes for subtitles but most of them don't. Most of the subtitles are manualy put in "bold" and/or "underline" font. (sometimes only 1 or another). Some documents have a subtitle starting with a number and a subsubtitle starting with a letter.

And then there Is me, who barely has experience with all of this. I think I'll need to write a lot of "if-else" statements to be able to extract the text-chunks from all of these documents, no matter which document the program gets as an input but I'm really wondering if there would be another point of vieuw (a better one) from someone who's more experienced?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are some sample documents, all with a (slightly) different layout:
[From this file I can parse the textblocks already witht the code you can find above.][1]
The next links are from other 'types of' documents. These are not the only ones but there are too many different kinds because different people worked on these documents and  everybody has his way / knowledge on how to write a document.

- https://www.scribd.com/document/436242588/example-1
- https://www.scribd.com/document/436242590/example-2
- https://www.scribd.com/document/436242592/example-3
- https://www.scribd.com/document/436242589/example-4
- https://www.scribd.com/document/436242591/example-5
- https://www.scribd.com/document/436242593/example-6

I don't need subtitles or subsubtitles in my jsonstrings. I just need chunks of normal text. Small "blocks" of text basicly. For example in B, from subtitle 3, I would get 3 json-strings with 1 textblock in each of them. In example 4 all the parts that are separated by an empty line could be 1 textblock and so 1 jsonstring. I hope this explanation makes my original question more clear.

Comment: It would be easier to help you with suggestions etc. if you supplied some example documents and the output you'd like to extract from them.

Comment: I added some documents.

Comment: you should replace 'high amount of' by 'large number of' or something

Comment: @wander95 if you’re going to be a grammar police person then replace “by” with “with”

Comment: Well you do have a lot og garbage in garbage out to figure out - but there’s no magic bullet. Maybe start by extracting all text styled “normal”? Then reject text that is bold/italic/underlined. Then make sure you test with examples representative of all the possible variations in the input documents. Good luck!

Comment: @barny Thanks for the comment. it's a tricky job (I think) but I'll keep your feedback in mind.